# Crear header firmado peticion SOAP c#

Tags: c#, soap

estoy consumiendo un webServices escrito en Java y en la llamada a la peticion necesito que en el header de la petición vaya una firma X509Certificate2, un ejemplo de como deberia de quedar seria este: [Link externo](http://tech-sash.blogspot.com.es/2010/07/anatomy-of-signed-soap-message.html)

Lo estoy intentando creando un `WSHttpBinding`, configurándolo mediante código y estableciendo el certificado instalado en mi pc a traves de

```
servicio.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate.
```

Mi problema es que crea esta cabecera:

```
<s:Header>
  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Nombre Metodo al que llamo</a:Action>
  <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:et43534-0537-4756-8juf9-7cb56hd6e443</a:MessageID>
  <a:ReplyTo>
     <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
  </a:ReplyTo>
  <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">DIRECCION DEL WSDL</a:To>
```

Llevo bastantes dias con esto y no soy capaz.

Si alguien me ayuda lo agradeceria.

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te a dar un [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar este:

```
private static void Main()
{
    using (var client = new ServiceClient())
    using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        MessageHeader usernameTokenHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UsernameToken",
            "http://test.com/webservices", "username");
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(usernameTokenHeader);

        MessageHeader passwordTextHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("PasswordText",
            "http://test.com/webservices", "password");
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(passwordTextHeader);

        MessageHeader sessionTypeHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("SessionType",
            "http://test.com/webservices", "None");
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(sessionTypeHeader);

        string result = client.GetData(1);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

El visor de Service Trace muestra lo siguiente:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <UsernameToken xmlns="http://test.com/webservices">username</UsernameToken>
        <PasswordText xmlns="http://test.com/webservices">password</PasswordText>
        <SessionType xmlns="http://test.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
        <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:13332/Service1.svc</To>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService/GetData</Action>
    </s:Header>
</s:Envelope>
```

Eche un vistazo [OperationContextScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope.aspx) para más información.

> Otras informaciones de interés (Traducir del inglés) :
>
> - [Firmar SOAP usando el certificado (WSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4730157/8933039)
> - [Cómo firmar el encabezado de Soap personalizado?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/152522/8933039)
> - [Crear mensaje SOAP firmado como una cadena con C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981926/8933039)

Comment: No me sirve ya que no tengo que añadir a la cabecera un user-pasword. La cabecera tiene que quedar asi http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_xWUcYX5ldbA/TDVl5EEYByI/AAAAAAAAEyc/3P7u6LU8yxQ/s1600/example.bmp